# Multiple Files with the same name - what's the best way to distinguish them for retrieval

Tags: documentum

We store uploaded files in Documentum and in the event someone uploads files with the same name, we would like to be able to retrieve the correct file using the Rest API.

We store metadata (filename, etc.) in the database as part of a queue of work.  So a user will go in and pick the next item in the queue (in this case look at the uploaded file).  Currently we look up using the filename and return the first file which is not ideal.

I know you get the Document back (including object id) upon upload, and I was thinking about storing that along with the other metadata, and we can compare that, but I stumbled across an [article](https://www.tsgrp.com/2010/08/23/documentum-r_object_id-thoughts-and-best-practices/) suggesting this was a bad idea.

I'm new to Documentum, so how do others manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced article is correct. Using of `r_object_id` for external references is not good idea especially because of the possible future migration. Because `r_object_id` contains the docbase ID and when you migrate into a new docbase then all documents will have different `r_object_id`.

You can solve it by adding of a custom attribute to the document type, where you can store copy of the `r_object_id` value (can be implemented by TBO) or generate your own ID (it can be also implemented by TBO or DB sequence), when the attribute is not filled in yet. Then you can use this value as a unique reference to that uploaded document.

And when you migrate into another docbase in the future `r_object_id` will change but value of that custom attribute will still remain the same.

Comment: Is it possible to filter on the custom attribute?  We already have several custom attributes on the file and was leaning toward adding one for this.  Just wanted some educated answers since I'm new to this.  Thanks...

Comment: Yes, you can filter by that custom attribute. And it depends what do you use to access Documentum: DFC or DFS or REST API?

Comment: I'm using the sample code off of GitHub in C# .Net that uses Rest API.  We built some functionality on top of that and created a web service.